# error found in upgrading project:operator '=' is ambiguous and 'ios' : is not a class or namespace name

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-c++-6

The following line compile fine in vc6 but when I upgrade the project in vs2008,lots of error I have found but mainly 2 errors are there.

```
//open log file
   parent->m_LogFile.open(strFileName, ios::app | ios::out, filebuf::sh_read);
```

**Error:** error C2653: 'ios' : is not a class or namespace name

```
CString CReverseProxy::PutData(CString strData)
{
    CString strSW = "";

    CString strPayload;
    DWORD   dwRet;
    BYTE    SendBuffer[MAX_LEN];
    BYTE    RecvBuffer[MAX_RETURN_SIZE];
    ULONG   ulSendLength = sizeof(SendBuffer);
    ULONG   ulRecLength  = sizeof(RecvBuffer);

    while ((strData.GetLength() / 2) > 255)
    {
        strPayload  = strData.Mid(0, 510);
        strData     = strData.Delete(0, strPayload.GetLength());//error
```

**Error:** error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem could probably be fixed by using `std::ios` in your open, or `using std::ios` at the beginning of the file.

The second problem is caused by the fact `CString::Delete` returns an int. This is definitely not what you'd like to assign to `strData`, right? Just remove the assignment, the `Delete` will modify `strData` anyway.

Comment: Yes. In general, `ios` inherits from `ios_base`. In VS, `ios` is actually a typedef of a `basic_ios`, which inherits from `ios_base`. So the constants are exactly the same, and you can use either class to access them.

Comment: What includes does the file with that `open` have? You should make sure <ios> is eventually included (preferably not directly, but via another stream header).